# Create database with code First for WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, code-first

I developed a WPF application for the creation of a database.

I found an error concerning `EntityFramawork.dll`. Could you help me?

Here is the link to the application: [onedrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F4C7995BF8118245!1455)

[Using EF Code First and SqlCe in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771109/using-ef-code-first-and-sqlce-in-wpf)

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code that demonstrates the error en tell which error occurs. Don't expect us to download and run your code.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Nuget to install Entity Framework. The below article will explain how to use EF Code first. Step 4 shows how to use Nuget to install Entity Framework.

[Read this for instruction](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx)